# Can I use my computer while BitLocker is encrypting the system drive?

Tags: windows, bitlocker, windows-10

I am thinking of encrypting my Windows 10 laptop with BitLocker (although I am curious about the answer for other versions too). If I start the process I imagine it will take a while since I have lots of data on my system drive. While this is happening will I be able to use my laptop still?

Comment: As said, yes. Except that when I encrypted my data drive (HDD), youtube videos did not play (only the first half second would show). Strange, as all browser files (program and profile folder) are on the (already encrypted) other SSD. Everything else worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can still continue to work while BitLocker encrypts in the background.

Comment: I experienced the same thing with TrueCrypt. The encryption system keeps track of which blocks are encrypted. Programs can continue operate as they normally would, regardless of whether that particular file has been encrypted or not yet (or partially encrypted).

Comment: Im encrypting a drive right now and using the computer

Comment: You can ever reboot and it will pick up where it left off.